# Show that every element of $F(\alpha)$ not in $F$ is transcendental over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $E$ be a field extension of $F$ and $\alpha \in E$ be transcendental over $F$. Show that every element of $F(\alpha)$ not in $F$ is transcendental over $F$.

Please check my attempt at proving this. Feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

*Proof.* Let $\beta \in F(\alpha) \setminus F$ such that $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$. Then $\exists p(x) \in F[x], p(x) \neq 0$ such that $p(\beta) = 0$. We then write $p(x)$ as follows

$$p(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}x + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n}x^{n}, a_{i} \in F.$$

Applying the evaluation homomorphism $\phi_{\beta}: F[x] \to E,$

$$p(\beta) = 0 = a_{0} + a_{1}\beta + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n}\beta^{n}.$$

Since $\beta \in F(\alpha) \setminus F$, $\beta = \frac{q(\alpha)}{r(\alpha)}$ $\exists q(x), r(x) \in F[x]$ (please see question 1). Thus

$$a_{0} + a_{1}\beta + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n}\beta^{n} = a_{0} + a_{1}(\frac{q(\alpha)}{r(\alpha)}) + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n}(\frac{q(\alpha)}{r(\alpha)})^{n}.$$

Multiplying both sides with $(r(\alpha))^{n},$

$$(r(\alpha))^{n} (a_{0} + a_{1}(\frac{q(\alpha)}{r(\alpha)}) + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n}(\frac{q(\alpha)}{r(\alpha)})^{n}) = a_{0}(r(\alpha))^{n} + a_{1}q(\alpha)(r(\alpha))^{n-1} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n}(q(\alpha))^{n} = 0.$$

Thus we found a polynomial $g(x) \in F[x] \setminus \{0\}$ such that $g(\alpha) = 0$, contrary to the assumption that $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$. Therefore $\beta$ is transcendental over $F$. $\square$.

Some of my questions/clarifications (will probably ask more in the comments/answers):

1. How is $q(\alpha)$ related to $r(\alpha)$ in terms of their form? More importantly, how must they be related so that $\beta$ is guaranteed to be an element of $F(\alpha) \setminus F$? Must it be that $r(\alpha) \nmid q(\alpha), gcd(q(\alpha), r(\alpha)) = 1, $ or something else?

Comment: How do you know that $g(x)$ is not zero polynomial? For your question, $q(\alpha)$ and $r(\alpha)$ don't have to be related at all, but you can assume that $gcd(q(\alpha), r(\alpha)) = 1$, otherwise, just cancel out all common factors of $q$ and $r$.