# show that $x\in E$ is transcendental over $F$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E=F(x)$ to be the fraction field of the ring $F[x] $, show that $x\in E$ is transcendental over $F$

---

let $x\in E$ then, it exists the function $f(y)=y-x$  such that $f(x)=0$
, thus $x$ is algebraic in $E$
clearly, it doesn't exist the function $f(y)=y-x \in F$ because $x$ doesn't exists in $F$.

Assume that it exist  $f(y)\neq0 \in F$ such that $f(x)=0$ how can I show this is a contradiction.

Specially, when, for example $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ but $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over
$\mathbb{Q}$ I don't know, this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Also, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114701/show-that-every-element-of-f-alpha-not-in-f-is-transcendental-over-f), cant say I understand it, seemed too much for something simple. I thought it must be an easier way.

Comment: This is not clear.  Just defining $E=F(x)$ does not imply that $x$ is transcendental over $F$.  You have to know something about $F$ and $x$.

Comment: @lulu that's what the exercise states

Comment: Well, then it's false.  That is, $x$ might be transcendental over $F$ or it might not.  It depends on what $F,x$ are.  For example, if $x=0$ then $E=F$ and $x$ is actually in $F$.  Similarly, if $F=\mathbb Q(x)$ then, again, $x\in F$ so it is not transcendental over $F$.  If $F=\mathbb Q(x^2)$ then $E$ is quadratic over $F$, and again $x$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: @includeCMath I didn't follow, we need to show that $x$   is transcendental over  $F$, why you state "But since $x$  is transcendental over $F$"

Comment: @includeCMath: There is an assumption in what you write that $F[x]$ is the ring of polynomials. In general, it just means "the smallest ring containing $F$ and $x$ (in some pre-specified overring)". For example, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $x=\sqrt{2}$ is its own field of fractions, and $x$ there is not transcendental. One needs to say (or have it already known from context or notation) that $F[x]$ is the ring of all polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you are absolutely right. But then the question would make sense.
I point this out in my answer

Comment: @ArturoMagidin wait I got confused, does includeCMath answer is correct or not ?

Comment: @lupsnox: It depends on whether you know that "$F[x]$" represents the ring of all poynomials on the indeterminate $x$ with coefficients in $F$ or not.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Maybe this is useful, in the book it defines $F(a)=\{f(a): f(x) \in F[x]\}$ and $F(a)=\{f(a)/g(a)  : f(x),g(x) \in F[x] \}$

Comment: So it defines $F[x]$ earlier, as the ring of polynomials in the indeterminate $x$ with coefficients in $F$. P.S. "The book", as if there exists only one book in the entire universe?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you probably mean I should state the title of the book, the book isn't in English, it's from a small country that's why I didn't say the title . P.S I mean, in the book I have ofc.

Comment: @lupusnox: I know you meant the book you have. But it is useless for you to make references to a mysterious book if the only person who knows what you are talking about is you. If you are going to make a reference to a book, then  you should **absolutely** say what book it is, even if you have no reason to expect anyone else to have a handy copy.  If you don't, then don't mention the book: it just wastes everyone's time and everyone's bandwidth. Or it looks  like you trying to deflect blame for not being clear by pointing to some mysterious "the book".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am sorry, I didn't try to deflect the blame, the blame is mine, I was confused about this till it pointed out to me, that's why I didn't write the definition in my question, I just assume everyone uses the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The following answer works if we assume that $F(x)$ is isomorphic to the field of fractions of $F[X]$, where $F[X]$ is the ring of polynomials over $F$. Otherwhise as @lulu pointed out in the comments, we do not have enough information to give a proper answer!

Let $F$ be a field and $F(x)$ is isomorphic to $Quot(F[X])$. Let us call this isomorphism $\iota: Quot(F[X])\rightarrow F(x)$, $X\mapsto x$ Since it is an isomorphism, it is injective. From this we get that $\iota':F[X]\rightarrow F(x)$, $X\mapsto x$ is also injective, so it has trivial kernel. But this means there exist no polynomial $P$ in $F[X]$ (besides the zero polynomial) such that $\iota'(P) = 0$, hence $x$ is transcendental.

Comment: @lulu what about that then ?

Comment: I'm new to this forum. If someone helps me out how to draw an commutative diagram here I would appreciate it. It would be helpful to see through this argument

Comment: Otherwhise here is a link to the diagram:
https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZARgBoAGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQBFZiHACgDFkADUoBKEAF9S6TLnyEUAJlLFqdJq3b9eAD3FSZ2PASJlFahizaIQ-SdJAYj8ouRUWN128MqS1MKABzeCJQADMAJwgAWyQAZhocCCQydSt2AB0M-Bx6AHJSAAIhLOj6NDgkwp17cKjYxDcQJJSaS00bLJz6IpKMsoqqmoMQSJikZWbkxDiRsYbJlsRiOfr4xOnyCUoJIA

Comment: @lupusnox: This question *assumes* that $F[X]$ is the ring of polynomials over $F$, which is an assumption about $F$ and $x$, exactly what lulu said you needed to do in order to answer the question.

Comment: You can put the image but clicking on the icon "image" which is located above the line you write your answer.

Comment: @lupusnox  as I said, if you make more assumptions about $F,x$ then you can say more.  But with no extra assumptions, you can't.